# How do you remove the margin automatically created by display: flex?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with display: flex with a bunch of divs (with class `favourites-entry` containing an item description (class `favourites-box` an image to the right of it).  The `favourites-entry` has no css apart from font. The image has float: right.  I set the `favourites-box` width to 90%, thinking the image would just go next to it, but the image sits under the `favourites-box` div.  I set the margin of the `favourites-box` to 0 for left and right, but for some reason it keeps creating extra margin on the right.

I tried setting the width of the `favourites-box` to lower values, but the image didn't move.  I also tried messing around with different position and display attributes on the `favourites-box` div, but nothing seemed to work as needed.

[image: picture showing what I am trying to achieve and the problem]

```css
.favourites-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.favourites-entry {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Sets fonts for the placeholder text inside inputs*/
}

.favourites-box {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /*Adds a shadow around the whole container*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*Makes corners of container rounded*/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Sets fonts for the placeholder text inside inputs*/
  border: 1px solid #929292;
  /*Adds a border around the inputs*/
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

img.favourites {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="favourites-entry">
  <div class="favourites-box">
    <h2 class="favourites">Vegetable Kofta - Starter</h2>
    Fried balls mixed with spices and besan, deep fried till crisp
    <button class="x-button">x</button>
  </div>
  <img src="image src" class="favourites">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want like this

```css
.favourites-entry {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.favourites-box {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /*Adds a shadow around the whole container*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*Makes corners of container rounded*/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Sets fonts for the placeholder text inside inputs*/
  border: 1px solid #929292;
  /*Adds a border around the inputs*/
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

img.favourites {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="favourites-entry">
  <div class="favourites-box">
    <h2 class="favourites">Vegetable Kofta - Starter</h2>
    Fried balls mixed with spices and besan, deep fried till crisp
    <button class="x-button">x</button>
  </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="favourites">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses flex-wrap and keeps all element on top (rather than aligning center)
Also - one suggestion from my side - Why don't you start using Bootstrap's 12 point Grid System - you'll love it.
Link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Current Solution :

```css
.favourites-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 100px auto;      
}

.favourites-entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;      
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Sets fonts for the placeholder text inside inputs*/
}

.favourites-box {
  flex: 0 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /*Adds a shadow around the whole container*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*Makes corners of container rounded*/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*Sets fonts for the placeholder text inside inputs*/
  border: 1px solid #929292;
  /*Adds a border around the inputs*/
  /*margin: 20px 0;*/
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

img.favourites {
  flex: 0 40%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="favourites-entry">
  <div class="favourites-box">
    <h2 class="favourites">Vegetable Kofta - Starter</h2>
    Fried balls mixed with spices and besan, deep fried till crisp
    <button class="x-button">x</button>
  </div>
  <img src="image url" class="favourites">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use bootstap since this is a school project, but thanks for the help :)